# JQuery Moble 1.4.0 - Panels are lovely but forms don't work in them

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panels

I've just got hold of JQuery 1.4.0 and it seems nicer than 1.3

However, I'm having a problem which is a real shame. The Panels are really nice in this and I'm trying to put some settings in the Panel. I want to use the Flipswitch and can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <h1>My Health Stats</h1>
         <a href="#mypanel1" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-left">Options</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="user" data-transition="none">User</a>        </li>
                <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="heart" data-transition="none">Obs</a>    </li>
                <li><a href="#page3" data-icon="calendar" data-    transition="none">Trend</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Trends</p>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox" id="flip-checkbox">
            </form>
    </div><!-- /content --> 
</div><!-- /page1 -->     

<div data-role="panel" data-theme="b" id="mypanel1">
    <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">   
        <h2>Settings</h2><hr><p>
        <b>Units</b><p>
        <form>
            <label for="flip-checkbox">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox" id="flip-checkbox" checked="">
        </form>
        <p>
            <button class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-right" data-rel="close">Close</button>


    </div>      
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

The Flipswitch in the page works fine. But in the panel it's just a normal checkbox.

Comment: you have placed `form` and its' elements inside _header_ div. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vf7d9/ Plus, dont use the same __ID__ for both switches in page and in panel.

Comment: Okay, I've changed that. It's still the same. I've removed the other switch altogether.

Comment: Okay, ion that jsfiddle link there is a new function with that makes it work.

Comment: `.enhanceWithin()` function?

Comment: $(function () {
        $("[data-role=panel]").enhanceWithin().panel();
    });